# Wolfram alpha gives incorrect inverse function

Tags: functions, polynomials, inverse-function, wolfram-alpha

I have trouble with Wolfram Alpha not fully calculating inverse of higher-order polynomial function. Function $$f(x)=3 x^6-5 x^4-4 x^2+8$$ (graph presented on a first photo [Graph of $f(x)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPU9V.png)) is not a one-to-one function. Was one to calculate its inverse the result would be either four different functions or $\pm$ sign which would result in the function having four different inverses for different domains of $x$, where $f(x)$ is one-to-one. Such answer is also given by wolfram [inverese of the function according to wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20f%28x%29%3D3%20x%5E%286%29-5%20x%5E%284%29-4%20x%5E%282%29%2B8), however, after copying the anser into geogebra the resulting graph is different from the plot given by wolfram  [Graph of function given by wolfram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsT7R.png), as seemingly two parts are missing, which is especially visible after comparing $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ on the same graph [Final wolfram's answer and starting $f(x)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyTMh.png). Is there some way to find the functions describing the middle part of the graph $f(x)$? Wolfram does realise the $4$ functions problem for simpler functions such as inverse of $$4 x^4-10 x^2+8$$ as it is able to give two distinct functions starting with $\pm$ as a result. [Inverse of simple function which would also be one-to-four](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%204%20x%5E%284%29-10%20x%5E%282%29%2B8)
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please type out the function you want an inverse for in the question and post the WA link.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. That function doesn't have an inverse anywhere at all.

Comment: @Moo i have typed a similar function with smaller coefficients for easier understanding. I added more links and photos too.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and re-fromat your question accordingly.

Comment: @TonyK well, of course it does, every function does in fact, however it is not defined by one function, for parabolas you would need two functions, hence the +/- in inverses, in my case I would need four different functions, however wolfram has only given me two, therefore two are still missing!

Comment: It seems you don't know what "inverse of a function" means.

Comment: You can do inverses of functions in given domains, for a function on top possible domains would be: -infinity<x<-1.75; -1.75<x<0; 0<x<1.75 and 1.75<x<infinity. As you can seen the first and last domains are satisfied, however inverse of function f(x) in  -1.75<x<0; 0<x<1.75 is missing. It is all about the ristrictions of the domain